# How to Redirect to view in using ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i use asp.net mvc5. i create a menu in right panel of site (layout). when user click in menu items, load page without refresh page. for to do thisو i use `Ajax.ActionLink`.

```
<aside class="right-panel flexcol">
<button class="accordion">Hotels</button>
    <div class="sub-panel flexcol">
@Ajax.ActionLink("View Hotels", "Index", "Hotel", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "pageContent" }, new { @class = "sub-menu" })
@Ajax.ActionLink("HotelType", "Index", "HotelType", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "pageContent" }, new { @class = "sub-menu" })

    </div>
```

and for call 'New Hotel' page, i use

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Create Hotel", "Create", "Hotel", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId = "pageContent" }, new { @class = "bluelink" })
```

These works properly. 
the problem: when i submit Create page, this page send to controller and if model fill a not valid data, page redirect to Create page without layout and css's.

```
@model ... Models.Hotel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout =null;
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Hotel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
        ApplyToDataBase(model, "uspInsertHotel");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the problem is in that fact that you are returning a partial view in case of invalid model, and this is not an ajax call. I can suggest couple of options, I hope they can help.

First, you can return not a partial view, but the whole view in that case. It probably is not really elegant solution, and it might lead to views duplication.

Another way - to use client-side validation, so you do not have to make a server call to just validate your input. In that case you will probably need to use jQuery validation plugin.